# I am trying to add a dist-tag to my pkg but I keep get 404 error

Tags: json, npm

I'm trying to add a dist-tag to my pkg, aka package.json. What am I doing wrong?

I am running

```
$ npm dist-tag add pkg@1.0.2 beta

17 verbose stack Error: missing : -/package/pkg/dist-tags
17 verbose stack     at makeError (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:302:12)
17 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:290:14)
17 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:210:14)
17 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:187:22)
17 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
17 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
17 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1048:10)
17 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
17 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
17 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:969:12)
18 verbose statusCode 404
19 verbose cwd /home/ubuntu/workspace/devenv
20 error Linux 4.9.17-c9
21 error argv "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin/npm" "dist-tag" "add" "pkg@1.0.2" "beta"
22 error node v6.11.2
23 error npm  v3.10.10
24 error code E404
25 error 404 missing : -/package/pkg/dist-tags
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a knowning Error: missing : -/package/**pkg**/dist-tags
you need to go to the registry site/package/**module_failed**/dist-tags mean you need the version referrer to dist-tags.
Try with the URL :

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/-/package/pkg/dist-tags
```

You need to show wich version you have to install as the "dist-tags" if you try to show this page : a JSON page with the version needed.

Need last nodejs and a update of NPM
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

```
//installation debian/ubuntu..
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo -i                    //login as root
apt-get install -y nodejs             //installation as root
exit       //disconnect root

npm install pkg@4.2.4
```

Comment: console is telling me the pkg doesn't exist. i used both the install and publish npm commands but to no avail

Comment: and after the update of nodejs if you didn't do the npm update too i add the command the my Post

Comment: using npm  v3.10.10

Comment: you are on Mac ?

Comment: all of your version is good :) but why you can installed??? any trouble with some URL, and proxy ???

Comment: when you try to open on your browser http://registry.npmjs.org/-/package/pkg/dist-tags do you get a 404 error ?

Comment: latest "4.2.4" comes up when click the link

Comment: to be honest i can't install any package using npm now

Comment: try the remove and reinstall

Comment: i go the version v8.5.0 in debian

Comment: and now installed the version + pkg@4.2.4 added 126 packages in 15.334s :) done

Comment: @Alex Lazarev you need to update your version i tested on debian and i put the process to the POST. regards